# Is there any way to get or calculate the velocity of a ScrollView?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm working on a react-native application and I was wondering, using a `<ScrollView>` if there were a way to get the current velocity?

I noticed the hook `onScroll` which returns a bunch of data including the `nativeEvent` object, but I couldn't find anything for the velocity.

Any suggestion?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

By velocity, I suppose, you mean pixels/second, right? You may have to maintain a timer and use `onScroll` method to get current scroll height.

```
<ScrollView onScroll={this.handleScroll} />
```

`handleScroll` would calculate velocity. The code may require refinement.

```
handleScroll: function(event: Object) {
 console.log((old_offset - event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y) / time);
 old_offset = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
}
```

Initialize old_offset back at the top of your file as `old_offset=0`

How to get `time`? You can use `performance.now()`. It is supported by chrome, as well as mozilla.

*Do not use `new Date()`. It is highly discouraged by the community*

```
handleScroll: function(event: Object) {
 var time = last_time_scroll_completed - performance.now()
 console.log((old_offset - event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y) / time);
 old_offset = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
 last_time_scroll_completed = performance.now();
}
```

**PLEASE NOTE**

This is just a notion (almost a pseudo-code). I have not tried this code, it may not work at all. It's something that I made up on the fly. Good luck!